# Send Win10 Notification from Windows Service .net Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I am trying to fire a Windows 10 notification from an Windows Service App, but I could not see how to make one from a background Windows Service.

Is this possible to be made?

Comment: [Maybe this hels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Btw, i googled your question, i.e.: "notification from an Windows Service" ^^